# Show Bundle product default price based on default product on category page

Tags: bundle, magento2, categories, price

I'm trying to get the default bundle price on the list.phtml.
By default it shows the min and max price, I need to have the price based on the selected default options.
How can I retrieve this informations on

By default it's

`<?php echo $block->getProductPrice( $_product );?>`

Thanks for your help